# How to make webpage content not to get collapse or disposition when browser re-sized

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I have created a webpage and some divisions, spans inside it but when I Re-size the browser's window the division and spans get disposition and collapse or placed over each other, Please tell me a solution for this problem as the whole webpage content remain as it is on re-sizing browsers window just like google.com.

Edit#01-
This is the Code Snippet:-

```
<html><head><title>Demo</title>


</head>
<body style="
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;    
">
<div id="header" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom: darkblue;
"><div style="
    margin-top: 17px;
"><span style="
    margin-left: 257px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
">Header</span></div>

</div>
<div id="content" style="
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-right: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-left: solid 1px blue;
  border-right: solid 1px blue;
  background: lavander;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.22);
">
<div style="
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px darkblue;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
  margin-bottom: 11px;
">Content</div>

 <input type="Email" name="email" title="Email" id="email"      placeholder="Enter       your email here" required="required" spellcheck="false"    style="
  margin-left: 21px;
  height: 37px;
  width: 590px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 21px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
 "><br>

<input type="password" name="pass" title="Password" id="pass" placeholder="Enter your Password here" required="required" spellcheck="false" style="
margin-left: 21px;
height: 37px;
width: 590px;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 1em;
outline: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: blue;
padding: 5px;
margin-right: 21px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
"><br>
 <hr style="
    width: 589px;
    border: solid 1px darkblue;
           "><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Set a min-width on your top level container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you provided some code, we could easily show you where and what to modify, and solve your issue. next time, please provide some code sample of the relevant part of your code.
2. wrap ALL your html content (inside the `<body>`) with a `div` with the following style: `width:100%;min-width:1200px`

note: change `1200px` to what fits you the best.

hope that helps, again, next time please provide code with your question.

hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

After updating your code, here is your solution:

change

```
<body style="
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;    
">
```

to:

```
<body style="
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%; 
    min-width:1200px;   
    position:relative;
">
```

Comment: Hey, I have posted it, Now.

Comment: Nothing Changed it's display is still inappropriate.

Comment: try to add `position:relative` to body style as well